# How to troubleshoot 500 error when deploying a Web Role to development fabric

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

My web role is intended to run an ASP.NET application. I tried to publish the application to local IIS and it runs smoothly. But when I press F5 to run it in Azure development fabric, it gives me this:

[image]

Not sure how to troubleshoot this...

Actually, the page title shows up at first, and then it changed to 500 error.

Comment: see my blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/10/25/debugging-http-500-internal-server-error-with-the-windows-azure-sdk.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can turn CustomErrors off in your web.config to see the details behind your 500 error.

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

Just be sure not to deploy to production with this setting.